# Reversing CRC32(a)

Tags: c, reverse-engineering, checksum, crc, crc32

I am trying to put into practice what I read in this document:
https://sar.informatik.hu-berlin.de/research/publications/SAR-PR-2006-05/SAR-PR-2006-05_.pdf

I'm using the CRC32 with Normal Polynimal = 0x04C11DB7. I build the table and reverse table. The table for CRC should be right, but I don't know if the reverse table is correct. below you will find the code to generate the tables and to try to force the crc to a fixed position.

Can you give me some advice? Where am I doing wrong?

```
#define CRCPOLY  0x04C11DB7
#define CRCPOLYR  0xEDB88320
#define INITXOR  0xFFFFFFFF
#define FINALXOR 0xFFFFFFFF


static uint32_t crc_table[256];
static uint32_t crc_revtable[256];

void make_crc_table()
{
    for (uint32_t byte = 0; byte <= 0xFF; byte++ )
    {
        uint32_t crc = (byte << 24);

        for (uint8_t bit = 0; bit < 8; bit++ )
        {
            if (crc & 0x80000000)
            {
                crc = (crc << 1) ^ CRCPOLY;
            }
            else
            {
                crc = (crc << 1);
            }
        }

        crc_table[ byte ] = crc;
    }
}

void make_crc_revtable()
{
    for (uint32_t byte = 0; byte < 256; byte++)
    {
        uint32_t crc = byte;

        for (uint8_t bit = 0; bit < 8; bit++)
        {
            if ((crc & 1) != 0)
            {
                crc = (crc >> 1) ^ CRCPOLYR;
            }
            else
            {
                crc >>= 1;
            }
        }

        crc_revtable[byte] = crc;
    }
}


int crc32(uint8_t *buffer, size_t length)
{
    uint32_t crcreg = INITXOR;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        crcreg = crc_table[ (buffer[i]  ^ (crcreg >> 24)) & 0xFF ] ^ (crcreg << 8);
    }

    return crcreg ^ FINALXOR;
}

void fix_crc_pos(uint8_t *buffer, int length, uint32_t tcrcreg, int fix_pos)
{
    int i;

    // make sure fix_pos is within 0..(length-1)
    fix_pos = ((fix_pos % length) + length) % length;

    // calculate crc register at position fix_pos; this is essentially crc32()
    uint32_t crcreg = INITXOR;
    for (i = 0; i < fix_pos; ++i) {
        crcreg = crc_table[ (buffer[i] ^ (crcreg >> 24)) & 0xFF ] ^ (crcreg << 8);
    }

    // inject crcreg as content
    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        buffer[fix_pos + i] = (crcreg >> i * 8) & 0xFF;
    }

    // calculate crc backwards to fix_pos, beginning at the end
    tcrcreg ^= FINALXOR;
    for (i = length - 1; i >= fix_pos; --i) {
        tcrcreg = crc_revtable[tcrcreg & 0xFF] ^ buffer[i] ^ (tcrcreg >> 8);
    }

    // inject new content
    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        buffer[fix_pos + i] = (tcrcreg >> i * 8) & 0xFF;
    }
}


int main()
{
    make_crc_table();
    make_crc_revtable();

    // Check valid CRC32(a)
    char crc32_check_txt[] = "123456789";
    uint32_t  crc32_check = 0xFC891918;

    uint32_t crc = crc32((uint8_t*)crc32_check_txt, std::strlen(crc32_check_txt));

    if(crc != crc32_check)
        return -1;


    // Change 1 byte and restore the previus CRC
    crc32_check_txt[0] = '4';

    fix_crc_pos((uint8_t*)crc32_check_txt, std::strlen(crc32_check_txt), crc32_check, 4);


    // Verify CRC32
    crc = crc32((uint8_t*)crc32_check_txt, std::strlen(crc32_check_txt));

    if(crc != crc32_check)
        return -1;

    return 0;
}
```

The tables:

```
CRCa Table
0x00000000, 0x04c11db7, 0x09823b6e, 0x0d4326d9, 0x130476dc, 0x17c56b6b, 0x1a864db2, 0x1e475005,
0x2608edb8, 0x22c9f00f, 0x2f8ad6d6, 0x2b4bcb61, 0x350c9b64, 0x31cd86d3, 0x3c8ea00a, 0x384fbdbd,
0x4c11db70, 0x48d0c6c7, 0x4593e01e, 0x4152fda9, 0x5f15adac, 0x5bd4b01b, 0x569796c2, 0x52568b75,
0x6a1936c8, 0x6ed82b7f, 0x639b0da6, 0x675a1011, 0x791d4014, 0x7ddc5da3, 0x709f7b7a, 0x745e66cd,
0x9823b6e0, 0x9ce2ab57, 0x91a18d8e, 0x95609039, 0x8b27c03c, 0x8fe6dd8b, 0x82a5fb52, 0x8664e6e5,
0xbe2b5b58, 0xbaea46ef, 0xb7a96036, 0xb3687d81, 0xad2f2d84, 0xa9ee3033, 0xa4ad16ea, 0xa06c0b5d,
0xd4326d90, 0xd0f37027, 0xddb056fe, 0xd9714b49, 0xc7361b4c, 0xc3f706fb, 0xceb42022, 0xca753d95,
0xf23a8028, 0xf6fb9d9f, 0xfbb8bb46, 0xff79a6f1, 0xe13ef6f4, 0xe5ffeb43, 0xe8bccd9a, 0xec7dd02d,
0x34867077, 0x30476dc0, 0x3d044b19, 0x39c556ae, 0x278206ab, 0x23431b1c, 0x2e003dc5, 0x2ac12072,
0x128e9dcf, 0x164f8078, 0x1b0ca6a1, 0x1fcdbb16, 0x018aeb13, 0x054bf6a4, 0x0808d07d, 0x0cc9cdca,
0x7897ab07, 0x7c56b6b0, 0x71159069, 0x75d48dde, 0x6b93dddb, 0x6f52c06c, 0x6211e6b5, 0x66d0fb02,
0x5e9f46bf, 0x5a5e5b08, 0x571d7dd1, 0x53dc6066, 0x4d9b3063, 0x495a2dd4, 0x44190b0d, 0x40d816ba,
0xaca5c697, 0xa864db20, 0xa527fdf9, 0xa1e6e04e, 0xbfa1b04b, 0xbb60adfc, 0xb6238b25, 0xb2e29692,
0x8aad2b2f, 0x8e6c3698, 0x832f1041, 0x87ee0df6, 0x99a95df3, 0x9d684044, 0x902b669d, 0x94ea7b2a,
0xe0b41de7, 0xe4750050, 0xe9362689, 0xedf73b3e, 0xf3b06b3b, 0xf771768c, 0xfa325055, 0xfef34de2,
0xc6bcf05f, 0xc27dede8, 0xcf3ecb31, 0xcbffd686, 0xd5b88683, 0xd1799b34, 0xdc3abded, 0xd8fba05a,
0x690ce0ee, 0x6dcdfd59, 0x608edb80, 0x644fc637, 0x7a089632, 0x7ec98b85, 0x738aad5c, 0x774bb0eb,
0x4f040d56, 0x4bc510e1, 0x46863638, 0x42472b8f, 0x5c007b8a, 0x58c1663d, 0x558240e4, 0x51435d53,
0x251d3b9e, 0x21dc2629, 0x2c9f00f0, 0x285e1d47, 0x36194d42, 0x32d850f5, 0x3f9b762c, 0x3b5a6b9b,
0x0315d626, 0x07d4cb91, 0x0a97ed48, 0x0e56f0ff, 0x1011a0fa, 0x14d0bd4d, 0x19939b94, 0x1d528623,
0xf12f560e, 0xf5ee4bb9, 0xf8ad6d60, 0xfc6c70d7, 0xe22b20d2, 0xe6ea3d65, 0xeba91bbc, 0xef68060b,
0xd727bbb6, 0xd3e6a601, 0xdea580d8, 0xda649d6f, 0xc423cd6a, 0xc0e2d0dd, 0xcda1f604, 0xc960ebb3,
0xbd3e8d7e, 0xb9ff90c9, 0xb4bcb610, 0xb07daba7, 0xae3afba2, 0xaafbe615, 0xa7b8c0cc, 0xa379dd7b,
0x9b3660c6, 0x9ff77d71, 0x92b45ba8, 0x9675461f, 0x8832161a, 0x8cf30bad, 0x81b02d74, 0x857130c3,
0x5d8a9099, 0x594b8d2e, 0x5408abf7, 0x50c9b640, 0x4e8ee645, 0x4a4ffbf2, 0x470cdd2b, 0x43cdc09c,
0x7b827d21, 0x7f436096, 0x7200464f, 0x76c15bf8, 0x68860bfd, 0x6c47164a, 0x61043093, 0x65c52d24,
0x119b4be9, 0x155a565e, 0x18197087, 0x1cd86d30, 0x029f3d35, 0x065e2082, 0x0b1d065b, 0x0fdc1bec,
0x3793a651, 0x3352bbe6, 0x3e119d3f, 0x3ad08088, 0x2497d08d, 0x2056cd3a, 0x2d15ebe3, 0x29d4f654,
0xc5a92679, 0xc1683bce, 0xcc2b1d17, 0xc8ea00a0, 0xd6ad50a5, 0xd26c4d12, 0xdf2f6bcb, 0xdbee767c,
0xe3a1cbc1, 0xe760d676, 0xea23f0af, 0xeee2ed18, 0xf0a5bd1d, 0xf464a0aa, 0xf9278673, 0xfde69bc4,
0x89b8fd09, 0x8d79e0be, 0x803ac667, 0x84fbdbd0, 0x9abc8bd5, 0x9e7d9662, 0x933eb0bb, 0x97ffad0c,
0xafb010b1, 0xab710d06, 0xa6322bdf, 0xa2f33668, 0xbcb4666d, 0xb8757bda, 0xb5365d03, 0xb1f740b4,

CRCa Rev Table
0x00000000, 0x77073096, 0xee0e612c, 0x990951ba, 0x076dc419, 0x706af48f, 0xe963a535, 0x9e6495a3,
0x0edb8832, 0x79dcb8a4, 0xe0d5e91e, 0x97d2d988, 0x09b64c2b, 0x7eb17cbd, 0xe7b82d07, 0x90bf1d91,
0x1db71064, 0x6ab020f2, 0xf3b97148, 0x84be41de, 0x1adad47d, 0x6ddde4eb, 0xf4d4b551, 0x83d385c7,
0x136c9856, 0x646ba8c0, 0xfd62f97a, 0x8a65c9ec, 0x14015c4f, 0x63066cd9, 0xfa0f3d63, 0x8d080df5,
0x3b6e20c8, 0x4c69105e, 0xd56041e4, 0xa2677172, 0x3c03e4d1, 0x4b04d447, 0xd20d85fd, 0xa50ab56b,
0x35b5a8fa, 0x42b2986c, 0xdbbbc9d6, 0xacbcf940, 0x32d86ce3, 0x45df5c75, 0xdcd60dcf, 0xabd13d59,
0x26d930ac, 0x51de003a, 0xc8d75180, 0xbfd06116, 0x21b4f4b5, 0x56b3c423, 0xcfba9599, 0xb8bda50f,
0x2802b89e, 0x5f058808, 0xc60cd9b2, 0xb10be924, 0x2f6f7c87, 0x58684c11, 0xc1611dab, 0xb6662d3d,
0x76dc4190, 0x01db7106, 0x98d220bc, 0xefd5102a, 0x71b18589, 0x06b6b51f, 0x9fbfe4a5, 0xe8b8d433,
0x7807c9a2, 0x0f00f934, 0x9609a88e, 0xe10e9818, 0x7f6a0dbb, 0x086d3d2d, 0x91646c97, 0xe6635c01,
0x6b6b51f4, 0x1c6c6162, 0x856530d8, 0xf262004e, 0x6c0695ed, 0x1b01a57b, 0x8208f4c1, 0xf50fc457,
0x65b0d9c6, 0x12b7e950, 0x8bbeb8ea, 0xfcb9887c, 0x62dd1ddf, 0x15da2d49, 0x8cd37cf3, 0xfbd44c65,
0x4db26158, 0x3ab551ce, 0xa3bc0074, 0xd4bb30e2, 0x4adfa541, 0x3dd895d7, 0xa4d1c46d, 0xd3d6f4fb,
0x4369e96a, 0x346ed9fc, 0xad678846, 0xda60b8d0, 0x44042d73, 0x33031de5, 0xaa0a4c5f, 0xdd0d7cc9,
0x5005713c, 0x270241aa, 0xbe0b1010, 0xc90c2086, 0x5768b525, 0x206f85b3, 0xb966d409, 0xce61e49f,
0x5edef90e, 0x29d9c998, 0xb0d09822, 0xc7d7a8b4, 0x59b33d17, 0x2eb40d81, 0xb7bd5c3b, 0xc0ba6cad,
0xedb88320, 0x9abfb3b6, 0x03b6e20c, 0x74b1d29a, 0xead54739, 0x9dd277af, 0x04db2615, 0x73dc1683,
0xe3630b12, 0x94643b84, 0x0d6d6a3e, 0x7a6a5aa8, 0xe40ecf0b, 0x9309ff9d, 0x0a00ae27, 0x7d079eb1,
0xf00f9344, 0x8708a3d2, 0x1e01f268, 0x6906c2fe, 0xf762575d, 0x806567cb, 0x196c3671, 0x6e6b06e7,
0xfed41b76, 0x89d32be0, 0x10da7a5a, 0x67dd4acc, 0xf9b9df6f, 0x8ebeeff9, 0x17b7be43, 0x60b08ed5,
0xd6d6a3e8, 0xa1d1937e, 0x38d8c2c4, 0x4fdff252, 0xd1bb67f1, 0xa6bc5767, 0x3fb506dd, 0x48b2364b,
0xd80d2bda, 0xaf0a1b4c, 0x36034af6, 0x41047a60, 0xdf60efc3, 0xa867df55, 0x316e8eef, 0x4669be79,
0xcb61b38c, 0xbc66831a, 0x256fd2a0, 0x5268e236, 0xcc0c7795, 0xbb0b4703, 0x220216b9, 0x5505262f,
0xc5ba3bbe, 0xb2bd0b28, 0x2bb45a92, 0x5cb36a04, 0xc2d7ffa7, 0xb5d0cf31, 0x2cd99e8b, 0x5bdeae1d,
0x9b64c2b0, 0xec63f226, 0x756aa39c, 0x026d930a, 0x9c0906a9, 0xeb0e363f, 0x72076785, 0x05005713,
0x95bf4a82, 0xe2b87a14, 0x7bb12bae, 0x0cb61b38, 0x92d28e9b, 0xe5d5be0d, 0x7cdcefb7, 0x0bdbdf21,
0x86d3d2d4, 0xf1d4e242, 0x68ddb3f8, 0x1fda836e, 0x81be16cd, 0xf6b9265b, 0x6fb077e1, 0x18b74777,
0x88085ae6, 0xff0f6a70, 0x66063bca, 0x11010b5c, 0x8f659eff, 0xf862ae69, 0x616bffd3, 0x166ccf45,
0xa00ae278, 0xd70dd2ee, 0x4e048354, 0x3903b3c2, 0xa7672661, 0xd06016f7, 0x4969474d, 0x3e6e77db,
0xaed16a4a, 0xd9d65adc, 0x40df0b66, 0x37d83bf0, 0xa9bcae53, 0xdebb9ec5, 0x47b2cf7f, 0x30b5ffe9,
0xbdbdf21c, 0xcabac28a, 0x53b39330, 0x24b4a3a6, 0xbad03605, 0xcdd70693, 0x54de5729, 0x23d967bf,
0xb3667a2e, 0xc4614ab8, 0x5d681b02, 0x2a6f2b94, 0xb40bbe37, 0xc30c8ea1, 0x5a05df1b, 0x2d02ef8d,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the code in the question. One issue was that CRC injection was storing the bytes in reverse order. I unfolded the loop for the injection code to make the ordering clear. The code to generate the reverse CRC table uses the normal CRC. The code to reverse the CRC xor's buffer data into the most significant byte of the CRC.

```
#include <iostream>

#define CRCPOLY  0x04C11DB7
#define INITXOR  0xFFFFFFFF
#define FINALXOR 0xFFFFFFFF

static uint32_t crc_table[256];
static uint32_t crc_revtable[256];

void make_crc_table()
{
    for (uint32_t byte = 0; byte <= 0xFF; byte++ )
    {
        uint32_t crc = (byte << 24);
        for (uint8_t bit = 0; bit < 8; bit++ )
        {
            if (crc & 0x80000000)
                crc = (crc << 1) ^ CRCPOLY;
            else
                crc = (crc << 1);
        }
        crc_table[ byte ] = crc;
    }
}

void make_crc_revtable()
{
    for (uint32_t byte = 0; byte < 256; byte++)
    {
        uint32_t crc = byte;
        for (uint8_t bit = 0; bit < 8; bit++)
        {
            if ((crc & 1) != 0)
                crc = (crc >> 1) ^ (CRCPOLY >> 1) ^ 0x80000000u;
            else
                crc >>= 1;
        }
        crc_revtable[byte] = crc;
    }
}


int crc32(uint8_t *buffer, size_t length)
{
    uint32_t crcreg = INITXOR;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        crcreg = crc_table[ (buffer[i]  ^ (crcreg >> 24)) & 0xFF ] ^ (crcreg << 8);
    }
    return crcreg ^ FINALXOR;
}

void fix_crc_pos(uint8_t *buffer, int length, uint32_t tcrcreg, int fix_pos)
{
    int i;

    // make sure fix_pos is within 0..(length-1)
    fix_pos = ((fix_pos % length) + length) % length;

    // calculate crc register at position fix_pos; this is essentially crc32()
    uint32_t crcreg = INITXOR;
    for (i = 0; i < fix_pos; ++i) {
        crcreg = crc_table[(buffer[i]^(crcreg>>24))&0xff]^(crcreg<<8);
    }

    // inject crcreg as content
    buffer[fix_pos + 0] = (crcreg >> 24) & 0xFF;
    buffer[fix_pos + 1] = (crcreg >> 16) & 0xFF;
    buffer[fix_pos + 2] = (crcreg >>  8) & 0xFF;
    buffer[fix_pos + 3] = (crcreg >>  0) & 0xFF;

    // calculate crc backwards to fix_pos, beginning at the end
    tcrcreg ^= FINALXOR;
    for (i = length - 1; i >= fix_pos; --i) {
        tcrcreg = crc_revtable[tcrcreg&0xff]^(tcrcreg>>8)^(((uint32_t)buffer[i])<<24);
    }

    // inject new content
    buffer[fix_pos + 0] = (tcrcreg >> 24) & 0xFF;
    buffer[fix_pos + 1] = (tcrcreg >> 16) & 0xFF;
    buffer[fix_pos + 2] = (tcrcreg >>  8) & 0xFF;
    buffer[fix_pos + 3] = (tcrcreg >>  0) & 0xFF;
}

int main()
{
    make_crc_table();
    make_crc_revtable();

    // Check valid CRC32(a)
    char crc32_check_txt[] = "123456789";
    uint32_t  crc32_check = 0xFC891918;

    uint32_t crc = crc32((uint8_t*)crc32_check_txt, std::strlen(crc32_check_txt));

    if(crc != crc32_check){
        std::cout << "error on forward crc\n";
        return 0;
    }

    // Change 1 byte and restore the previus CRC
    crc32_check_txt[0] = '4';

    fix_crc_pos((uint8_t*)crc32_check_txt, (int) std::strlen(crc32_check_txt), crc32_check, 4);

    // Verify CRC32
    crc = crc32((uint8_t*)crc32_check_txt, std::strlen(crc32_check_txt));

    if(crc != crc32_check){
        std::cout << "error on backward crc\n";
        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

This is an alternative approach. To cycle a CRC backwards, you can multiply a CRC by 1/pow(2, number of bits to be cycled backwards) == CRC * pow(2, -1-(number of bits to cycle backwards) % CRC_POLY.

```
#include <iostream>

#define CRCPOLY  0x04C11DB7
#define INITXOR  0xFFFFFFFF
#define FINALXOR 0xFFFFFFFF

static uint32_t crc_table[256];

void make_crc_table()
{
    for (uint32_t byte = 0; byte <= 0xFF; byte++ )
    {
        uint32_t crc = (byte << 24);

        for (uint8_t bit = 0; bit < 8; bit++ )
        {
            if (crc & 0x80000000)
            {
                crc = (crc << 1) ^ CRCPOLY;
            }
            else
            {
                crc = (crc << 1);
            }
        }

        crc_table[ byte ] = crc;
    }
}

int crc32(uint8_t *buffer, size_t length)
{
    uint32_t crcreg = INITXOR;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        crcreg = crc_table[ (buffer[i]  ^ (crcreg >> 24)) & 0xFF ] ^ (crcreg << 8);
    }

    return crcreg ^ FINALXOR;
}

// carryless multiply modulo crc polynomial
uint32_t MpyModCrc(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) // (a*b)%crc
{
uint32_t pd = 0;
uint32_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < 32; i++){
        pd = (pd<<1)^((0-(pd>>31))&0x04c11db7u);
        pd ^= (0-(b>>31))&a;
        b <<= 1;
    }
    return pd;
}

// exponentiate by repeated squaring modulo crc
uint32_t PowModCrc(uint32_t p)          // pow(2,p)%crc
{
uint32_t prd = 0x1u;                    // current product
uint32_t sqr = 0x2u;                    // current square
    while(p){
        if(p&1)
            prd = MpyModCrc(prd, sqr);
        sqr = MpyModCrc(sqr, sqr);
        p >>= 1;
    }
    return prd;
}

void fix_crc_pos(uint8_t *buffer, int length, uint32_t tcrcreg, int fix_pos)
{
uint32_t crc;                                   // crc
uint32_t par;                                   // parities
uint32_t pmr;                                   // 1/pow(2, number of bits to cycle backwards)
size_t i;

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)                      // zero out data to be replaced
        buffer[fix_pos+i] = 0;
    pmr = PowModCrc(-1-((length-fix_pos)*8));   // pmr = 1/pow(2, number of bits to cycle backwards)
    crc = crc32(buffer, length);                // generate crc
    crc ^= tcrcreg;                             // adjust crc
    par = MpyModCrc(crc, pmr);                  // par = (crc*pmr)%crc
    buffer[fix_pos+0] = (uint8_t)(par>>24);     // store parities
    buffer[fix_pos+1] = (uint8_t)(par>>16);
    buffer[fix_pos+2] = (uint8_t)(par>> 8);
    buffer[fix_pos+3] = (uint8_t)(par>> 0);
}

int main()
{
    make_crc_table();

    // Check valid CRC32(a)
    char crc32_check_txt[] = "123456789";
    uint32_t  crc32_check = 0xFC891918;

    uint32_t crc = crc32((uint8_t*)crc32_check_txt, std::strlen(crc32_check_txt));

    if(crc != crc32_check){
        std::cout << "error on forward crc\n";
        return 0;
    }

    // Change 1 byte and restore the previus CRC
    crc32_check_txt[0] = 'x';

    fix_crc_pos((uint8_t*)crc32_check_txt, (int) std::strlen(crc32_check_txt), crc32_check, 4);

    // Verify CRC32
    crc = crc32((uint8_t*)crc32_check_txt, std::strlen(crc32_check_txt));

    if(crc != crc32_check){
        std::cout << "error on backward crc\n";
        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Example using Visual Studio intrinsics (PCLMULQDQ) for carryless multiply. Since there is no borrowless divide, the inverse of the polynomial is used (generated by GenMPoly()), and a multiply is done, with the resulting quotient in the upper 64 bits of an XMM register, which in the code below is mt.m128i_u64[1], commented as just t[1].

So the sequence is carryless multiply two 32 bit values p = a · b, resulting in a 63 bit result (no carries so only 63 bit product). Multiply by inverse of poly to get quotient t = p/POLY. Multiply by poly to get truncated product t = t*POLY. Then the product modulo poly = p ^ t.

```
#define POLY  (0x104c11db7ull)
#define POLYM ( 0x04c11db7u)

static __m128i poly;                    /* poly */
static __m128i invpoly;                 /* 2^64 / POLY */

void GenMPoly(void)                     /* generate __m12i8 poly info */
{
uint64_t N = 0x100000000ull;
uint64_t Q = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 33; i++){
        Q <<= 1;
        if(N&0x100000000ull){
            Q |= 1;
            N ^= POLY;
        }
        N <<= 1;
    }
    poly.m128i_u64[0] = POLY;
    invpoly.m128i_u64[0] = Q;
}
// ...
// carryless multiply modulo crc
uint32_t MpyModCrc(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) // (a*b)%crc
{
__m128i ma, mb, mp, mt;
    ma.m128i_u64[0] = a;
    mb.m128i_u64[0] = b;
    mp = _mm_clmulepi64_si128(ma, mb, 0x00);      // p[0] = a*b
    mt = _mm_clmulepi64_si128(mp, invpoly, 0x00); // t[1] = (p[0]*((2^64)/POLY))>>64
    mt = _mm_clmulepi64_si128(mt, poly, 0x01);    // t[0] = t[1]*POLY
    return mp.m128i_u32[0] ^ mt.m128i_u32[0];     // ret =  p[0] ^ t[0]
}
// ...
int main()
{
    GenMPoly();
// ...
```

Comment: don't worry, deleted. I tried your code and it is working. I am left with the doubt about the error in my code. Thank you for your help

Comment: @GiGa - I updated my answer to include a fixed version of the question's code.

Comment: You were really kind

Comment: @GiGa - I was tied up with other projects, but I already had that alternate version that I first posted. Once I got the time, I was able to fix up the question's code and update my answer. As for the alternate version, most PC's have a carryless multiply, PCLMULQDQ, but it uses XMM registers, and C++ code would need intrinsics to use it, or it would need to be implemented in assembly code.

Comment: @GiGa - I added code to show the intrinsic version of the alternate version.